# Create a map of people's movements within a room using Power BI

Tags: routes, powerbi, visualization

I'm currently working with Power BI and analyzing people's interactions within a room. I would like to create a flow map based on people's movements, represented by arrows. However, I'm having trouble finding any visuals that show movement arrows and allow me to change the background.

I have spend couple of hours searching on google, chat gpt and youtube  and I have tried the visuals:

1. route map
2. flow map
3. synoptic-panel

All those solutions use existing maps which cannot be custimized. Morevoer, synoptic-panel does work with coordinates.
Do you know of any Power BI custom visuals that I could use?

Comment: Can you mock up a diagram of what your expected result should look like?

Answer (score 0):

i have done with cases similarly with yours. i would like to suggest you with 2 visuals and samples as attached. (if links cannot open feel free to leave your email address i will send you.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBd9o.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5btE.png)

Comment: Hi Sia. Thank you for your answer. Are you able to change the background to show a room map instead of a world map?

Comment: Hi Bob, sorry i cannot. if you want to see flows only without geographical map then i would like to suggest you with below visuals:
Chord as above; sankey; ribbon.